# UPDATE TABLE data WHERE SELECT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update data from a table. I've searched in Google and Stack, but I can't achieve this.

It's an Android App. When I click button "Cancel Subscription" it should update table 'assinaturas' on field 'isSubscribed' with 0.

This button, send to php this information (email and name):

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['nome']))
```

*Here is table usuarios:*
[image]

*Here is table podcasts:*
[image]

*Here is table assinaturas:*

[image: Table assinaturas]

The informations that I have are 'usuarios.email' and 'podcasts.nome'.

Here is one of my tryings:

```
                            UPDATE TABLE assinaturas 
                            SET isSubscribed = 0 
                            WHERE id_usuario IN (
                            SELECT      usr.id 
                            FROM        usuarios AS usr 
                            WHERE       usr.email = '$email'
                            ) 
                            AND id_podcast IN (
                            SELECT      pcst.id 
                            FROM        podcasts AS pcst 
                            WHERE       pcst.nome = '$nome'
                            )
```

With this query I've got syntax error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'TABLE assinaturas SET isSubscribed = 0 WHERE id_usuario IN ( '
>   at line 2

So, I receive **usuarios.email** and **podcasts.nome** and I need to *update* **assinaturas.isSubscribed** to **0 (zero)**.

I hope you can help me. Thx.

Comment: That looks like it should update the table when the conditions are met.  Perhaps you need to better describe what you want to do and provide more complete sample data.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Please add sample contents of `usuarios` and `podcasts`, and explain which rows in `assinaturas` should be updated. And it would be better if you posted text instead of images, so we can copy and paste into sqlfiddle. Either that, or make a sqlfiddle yourself.

Comment: Edited. I think it's clear now. @angelcool.net, I forgot the closing parenthesis in my question, but I'm using it. Ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UPDATE TABLE` is incorrect, remove the word TABLE:

```
UPDATE assinaturas 
SET isSubscribed = 0 
WHERE id_usuario IN (
    SELECT usr.id 
    FROM usuarios AS usr 
    WHERE usr.email = '$email'
) AND id_podcast IN (
    SELECT pcst.id 
    FROM  podcasts AS pcst 
    WHERE  pcst.nome = '$nome'
)
```

Comment: It worked! Awesome! Thank you so much. A dumb error, sorry.